# How can I merge multiple pivot tables in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I merge Excel pivot tables by their common factors?

Screenshot examples included below:

First pivot table:

[image: First pivot table]

Second pivot table:

[image: Second pivot table]

Merged pivot table:

[image: Merged pivot table]

Does anyone know how to do this in Excel (or better yet, VBA)?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to combine the underlying data into a single data table, and pivot off of that.